# WP_Query filters

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

question might seem dumb but i truly didn't find helpfull links
so im trying to do a simple query where i select the latest 10 posts and i want to be able to show only 1 post from those 10 in loop

my code looks like

```
  // Query latest 10 records
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    "order" => "DESC",
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'modified',


    ) );
```

For loop

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');

                    <?php the_title(); ?>


endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

endif;

Comment: which one of the 10 posts do you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the WP_Query exactly the same there's 2 ways I can think of which you could do this using various loops.

1) Grab the first post from the `posts` Array.

WP_Query has a bunch of [properties and methods](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties-and-methods) one of which is the `posts` array.

```
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // Grab the first post object
    $single_post = $the_query->posts[0];    // $post is reserved by global.

    // This only gives you access to object properties, not `the_*()` functions.
    echo $singe_post->post_title;

}

// Overwrite the global $post object
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // Grab the global post
    global $post;

    $post = $the_query->posts[0];  // Grab the first post object.
    setup_postdata( $post );        // Allows you to use `the_*()` functions. Overwrites global $post

    the_title();

    // Reset global $post back to original state
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

2) Rewind the query when necessary.

The following will loop through the loop as normal but at the end we'll rewind it. This ensures that should we want to loop through *all* the posts, it will include the first post. This method uses WP_Query::rewind_posts

```
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        $the_query->the_post();

        // Break out of the loop after displaying 1 post.
        if( $the_query->current_post >= 1 ) {
            break;
        }

        the_title();

    }

    // Rewind the posts back to index 0, or the beginning.
    $the_query->rewind_posts();

    // Always call after running a secondary query loop that uses  `the_post()`
    the_query->wp_reset_postdata();

}
```